# Python PIL putdata color must be int or tuple

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What I want to do is a code which creates an image from a list of pixels. Here is the code.

```
from PIL import Image
data=open("data")
data2=data.read()
dat=print (data2)
img = Image.new('RGB', (10000,10000))
img.putdata([data2])
img.save("prova_v2.jpg")
```

And the error that output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cicles\Desktop\img - copia.py", line 5, in <module>
    img.putdata([data2])
  File "C:\Users\cicles\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1671, in putdata
    self.im.putdata(data, scale, offset)
TypeError: color must be int or tuple
```

The data file that contains every RGB valour for every pixel inside an image. the format is `[(R,G,B), (R,G,B), (R,G,B)]` So a 2-line image with Red, Green and Blue pixels in the top row and Black, Grey and White pixels in the bottom row is like this:

```
[(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,255), (128,128,128), (0,0,0)]
```

Comment: Could you add the information about the error that occurred and provide the content in `data`? You can check the type of `data2` to make sure the content can be put into `img`.

Comment: As Hao Li mentiones above, we really need more information to exactly say what's going wrong. One suspicious thing I see is that you put `data2` in an additional array in the line `img.putdata([data2])`. That is _probably_ not what you want.

Comment: @HaoLi 
I did all the changes mentioned so it is now understandable.

Comment: @physicalattraction
I did all the changes mentioned so it is now understandable.

Comment: Please show a data file that would correspond to a 3 pixel wide by 2 pixel high image, with for example the top row Red, Green, Blue pixels and the bottom row Black, Grey and White pixels. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `[(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,255), (128,128,128), (0,0,0)]`

Comment: Please note that you should click `edit` under your question in future and make sure all the details are in there, rather than the comments.

Comment: So, how can you tell your image is 3x2 pixels and not 6x1 pixels or 2x3 pixels?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, it's my first question. And you can change the pixels on `img = Image.new('RGB',(10000, 10000))` by `img = Image.new('RGB',(3, 2))`

Comment: I was trying to say that isn't a very sensible way to store the pixels, because you can't deduce the image shape from the file. I mean it is inefficient, incomplete and slow. Is there some reason to use such an ill-suited format?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I changed the values because with the values that must have the image (569 x 929)I have an error

Comment: Why are you using that layout - it is not good. Can you change it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell What do you mean?

Comment: When you want to store a pixel of three RGB values that are a byte each, that will take 3 bytes of disk. If you store `(255,0,0), ` for each pixel, that means you are using 11-15 bytes per pixel, so you make the file 5x bigger than necessary and you make it about 100x slower to read.

Comment: @MarkSetchell But I must use this file, I don't have another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file format is a very poor choice, so you will have to spend ages parsing the data out, removing the parentheses and commas something like this mess:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image file, slurp the lot
with open('file.rgb') as f:
   s = f.read()

# Make a list of anything that looks like numbers using a regex - this is ugly and slow
l = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', s)

# Now make list of strings into Numpy array of uint8 and reshape
na = np.array(l, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2,3,3)

# Now make the Numpy array into a PIL Image
im = Image.fromarray(na)

# Save
im.save("prova_v2.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Try starting `IPython` or Python or whatever tool you normally use to write code. Paste in the first 3 lines, see what happens. Paste in the next 2 lines and print `s`. Paste in the next line and print `l`. Keep going, printing whatever variable I just created till you see how I got from A to B.